# Can you have custom @info colors?

Tags: string, console, output, julia

In Julia, I have a project where I have many calculations. Next is a tiny extract of what it could look like:

```
[ Info: Benders Solving with subtour constraints ---  ./Instances/tiny_instance_10.txt  ---
[ Info: Spent 0.039s in Benders decomposition
[ Info: Spent 0.035s in Master problem
[ Info: Spent 0.004s in subproblem
Objective : 47.80267061445823
[ Info: 4 Optimality Constraints created
[ Info: 4 Subtour Constraints created
[ Info: MILP Creating Model ---  ./Instances/tiny_instance_10.txt  ---
```

I mainly use `@info` to output data on console. `[ Info:` is in teal color, which is great and I would like to know if there exists a convenient way to get other colors? That would be better to read given I have many lines with `@info` to print.

Something like: `@info red "MyString"`?

I could not find in the [Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Logging/#Creating-events).

I believe if it is not easily makeable with @info, I will have to create my own print function?

Comment: You could switch to [printstyled](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.printstyled)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it yourself

```
macro myinfo(color, what)
    quote
        printstyled($what,color=$color)
    end
end
```

And now:

[image]